# How can I implement a dictionary attack on a multi-use pad?

Tags: dictionary, xor, pad

I'm taking Stanford University's cryptography class on Coursera (actually behind a couple of weeks :/ ), and I'm having a little trouble with the first assignment. The code below may be, or is certainly, overkill... When I ran into problems with this method, I scaled down and tried crib dragging with only one XORed result of two cipher texts and then checking the list of results manually.

While I understand the principles of breaking a multi-use pad, and I understand how crib dragging works, I don't see a practical way to evaluate the results of crib dragging... I spent about an hour or two plugging in different words and straining my eyes trying to find the partial English words in the results without much success. I feel there should be a way to use a short dictionary list of possible terms to search for and somehow automatically check the results. How can I do it?

This is my best attempt:

```
# XOR two hex encoded strings
def XOR(a, b):            
    return " ".join("".join([chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for (x, y) in zip(a ,b)]).split())

# Compares each of 10 ciphers with each other...results in 45 XORed results
def compareCiphers():     
    with open("ciphers.txt", "r") as f:
        ciphers = f.readlines()    

    with open("XORedCiphers.txt", "w") as f:
        n = 0
        for c in ciphers: 
            print "Cipher: " + c + "-----------------------------------------\n"
            for x in range(n, len(ciphers)):
                if ciphers[x] != c:        
                    print "\tXORed with cipher: " + ciphers[x]
                    result = XOR(ciphers[x], c)
                    print "\t\tResult:\t" + result + "\n\n"
                    f.write(result + "\n")     
            n += 1

# Drags each word of the dictionary across each XORed cipher text
def cribDrag():
    with open("XORedCiphers.txt", "r") as f:
        XORs = f.readlines()

    with open("/Users/aweeeezy/bin/dictionaries/dictionary.txt", "r") as d:
        for word in d:    
            for x in XORs:
                for index in range(0, len(x)):
                    test = XOR(x[index:], word)
                    if test.isalpha():
                        """ Something should go here to check if 'test' is an English
                        word...but I can't think of a practical way to do this """
                        print "\t" + test          

compareCiphers()
cribDrag()
```